# React jss overrides parent styles and retains child style

Tags: reactjs, jss

in using the [jss lib](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.9.0) in react with a custom theme that merges two themes together for use. Previously there was no problems but to type it correctly and create an ease of development, it was modified a bit of how the `createUseStyles` works. Here is an example of the usage **before** the change:

```
import { cn, createUseStyles, useTheme } from "@styling";

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  container: {
    width: "500px",
    height: "100px",
  }
});

const Child = ({extraStyles}:{extraStyles:string[]}) =>  {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const styles = useStyles({theme});
  return (
    <div className={cn(styles.container, ...extraStyles)}>
      
    </div>
  )
}


// parent

import { cn, createUseStyles, useTheme } from "@styling";
import Child from "@child";

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  large: {
    width: "999px",
    height: "999px",
  }
});

const Parent = () =>  {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const styles = useStyles({theme});
  return (
    <Child extraStyles={[styles.large]}/>
  )
}
```

where `cn` just combined the classes together. This would result in a stylesheet where the parents styles would override the childs, allowing for flexibility.

After some necessary modification the `createUseStyles` is typed and generated within the styling. It looks something like this:

```
//styling

import {
   createUseStyles as createStyles,
   useTheme,
   ThemeProvider,
   Styles,
} from "react-jss";

const createUseStyles = (styles) => {
  return (props) => {
    const tempTheme = useTheme();
    const temp = createStyles(styles);
    return temp({ ...props, theme: tempTheme });
  };
};

export { ThemeProvider, createUseStyles };
```

I have excluded the extra typing, but it was essentially to save the need to typescript `createUseStyles` and the usage of `useTheme` every single time within a component.

...But in doing so & in usage the exact same example as provided above with this new `createUseStyle`, the child injects it's style above the parents and doesn't pull in the props styling. Using `!important` on every single prop style is extremely tedious.

I'm confused why just pulling `useTheme` outside would break the injection structure (assuming that is the cause of this problem)?

Answer (score 0):

Possible, you can add `index` for `createUseStyles` to set order of injection, something like this:

```
// Child
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  container: {
    width: "500px",
    height: "100px",
  }
}, { index: 2 });

// Parent 
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  large: {
    width: "999px",
    height: "999px",
  }
}, { index: 1 });
```

I don't know how it works, if you need to add into every componente style or in entire stylesheet. The official documentation of React JSS isn't clear but it has in JSS API.